# Recursion, and not ending the recursion by return statement

Tags: recursion, go

I am doing binary search in this tree and expect the Find recursion to end when the result is true. It does have a result of true but even if it gets the true value and runs the return statement, it seems like continue to run and finally reach the value of `false`

How do I make this program end when it finds the value and returns?

http://play.golang.org/p/miWqRVo_XO

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Tree struct {
  Left  *Tree
  Value int64
  Right *Tree
}

func NewT(val int64) *Tree {
  return &Tree{
    Left:  new(Tree),
    Value: val,
    Right: new(Tree),
  }
}

func (T *Tree) Insert(val int64) *Tree {
  if T == nil {
    return &Tree{nil, val, nil}
  }
  if val < T.Value {
    T.Left = T.Left.Insert(val)
  } else {
    T.Right = T.Right.Insert(val)
  }
  return T
}

func (T *Tree) Find(val int64) bool {
  fmt.Printf("%v , %v\n", T.Value, val)
  fmt.Printf("%v\n", T.Value == val)

  if fmt.Sprintf("%v", T.Value) == fmt.Sprintf("%v", val) {
    fmt.Println("True and we do return true")
    return true
  }
  if val < T.Value {
    T.Left.Find(val)
  } else {
    T.Right.Find(val)
  }
  fmt.Println("False")
  return false
}

func main() {
  t1 := NewT(5)
  for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    t1 = t1.Insert(int64(i))
  }
  fmt.Println("Result:", t1.Find(7))
}
```

Output is

```
5 , 7
false
0 , 7
false
5 , 7
false
6 , 7
false
7 , 7
true
True and we do return true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be ignoring the return value of `Tree.Find` when you recurse into it.  If you pass on the return value, you should get the desired behaviour.  That is, modify the end of `Find` to read:

```
if val < T.Value {
    return T.Left.Find(val)
} else {
    return T.Right.Find(val)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was confused with the similar function Insert. Thanks James